# SQL Server Provisioning Tool

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Running under Server 2008, SQL Server 2005 SP2 has the option to "Add New Administrator" from the SQL Server 2005 Surface Ara Configuration. This launches the SQL Server 2005 User Provisioning Tool for Vista. You are then able to grant privileges such as Server SysAdmin role etc.

When I do this the privileges are copied across and appear to be saved but when I return to this tool it is clear that they have not been saved. Anybody else experience this or know how to "make it stick" ?

Comment: In case someone, like myself, comes by and found that the users actually aren't sticking, here's a related discussion I found helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/c76e67cf-9c6b-4c4f-a7be-0a998ddd808e/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the tool is simply not verifying that the privileges are already granted, and it's granting the privileges on every run, which is ok with me (you could check the members of the `sysadmin` server role.)